# Video editing missing feature(?)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I need that a movie clip strip is scaled and moved in different positions along the time. I am not using blender as 3d editor, but only the video editing mode.
I can't find a way to move the video in the screen.
I tried to apply the transform effect to it, but i can't change the parameters along the time, they are always fixed.
Keyframes are appliable only to 3d objects, not videoclips, nor effects.
Anyone knows how do that? If it is possible do that without using the videoclip as texture of some object.
Blender it is so powerful also as videoeditor, i am missing that feature

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry. I just found a tutorial about it.
Just add a keyframe on parameter (RMB->insert keyframe).
Documentation is not that clear.

Comment: Addons make this easier. Try this one: https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set keyframes on the values of the effect strip. Just press <kbd>i</kbd> while hovering the target value with your mouse and it will set a keyframe. You can also use <kbd>RMB</kbd> on a value and choose "Set keyframe".

[image: demo pic]

A little test to convince you:

[image: demo gif]

Isn't he cute! :3

Comment: In future, avoid uplaoding proprietary content and choose open source/free to distribute content, e.g. Blender Foudation Open Movies